# Find documents where all array field values matches predicate

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Given the following document schema

```
{
    "type": ["A", "B"]
}
```

where field *type* is an indexed field of *keyword* type.

I want to find documents for which all values of *type* field should match some predicate *p*.

Basically I need to check if all values from *type* field are present in another array. E.g. for ["A", "B", "C] doc above matches, for ["A", "D"] not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scripts` to workaround this. The idea here would be to check if all the elements of `doc` are present in `input_array`. Refer: [subsets-discussion](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/subsets/46488)

In version **6.3**, there's native support for this via `terms_set` query. Refer:
[terms-set-query-dsl](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-set-query.html)